# Need to add multiple answers to a single array

Tags: javascript

I need to add multiple questionnaires to use the same code/array. How can i do this?

```
// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = ["Apple", "Test"] ;
answers[1] = "Dynamic HTML";
answers[2] = "Netscape";
answers[3] = "Common Gateway Interface";
```

As you can see I've just tried adding my other answer onto the code array for a different quiz but it does not recognise the answer (Test). What is the best way of doing this? (is there an "or" command or something like that?

Here is my whole code:

```
// Insert number of questions
var numQues = 4;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(4);


// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = ["Apple", "Test"] ;
answers[1] = "Dynamic HTML", "Test";
answers[2] = "Netscape",  "Test";
answers[3] = "Common Gateway Interface", "Test";

// Do not change anything below here ...
function getScore(form) {
var score = 0;
var currElt;
var currSelection;
for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
currElt = i*numChoi;
for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
  currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
  if (currSelection.checked) {
    if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
      score++;
      break;
    }
  }
 }
}
score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
form.percentage.value = score + "%";
var correctAnswers = "";
for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
}
form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
} 
//  End -->
```

So just to make it easier to understand.. I want to have a few different quiz's link to this code to use for answers instead of repeating the whole code for each quiz. What modifications need to be done?

Comment: I'm lost after the thing you said _just to make it easier to understand_

Comment: I have various html quiz pages - all of them currently link to this code. Only the 1st quiz with answers Apple, Dynamic HTML, Netscape, or Common Gateway Interface work at the moment

Comment: For the second quiz I set all the answers to test but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want your answers array to be an array of arrays, should you have [ ] around the lines for 1, 2 and 3?

Like this ...

```
answers[0] = ["Apple", "Test"] ;
answers[1] = ["Dynamic HTML", "Test"];
answers[2] = ["Netscape", "Test"];
answers[3] = ["Common Gateway Interface", "Test"];
```

It might be easier to help if I could edit below that line asking me not to. I think you really want something like

```
currSelection.value == answers[i][j]
```

instead of

```
currSelection.value == answers[i]
```